# Is there a relation $\leq$ on $G$ such that $(G, \leq)$ is a directed set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and let $S$ be a finite
generating set. (For convenience, we always assume our generating
set is symmetric, i.e. $s\in S$ implies that $s^{-1}\in S$.) We
define the word length $||g||_S$ of an element $g\in G- \{e\}$, with
respect to the generators $S$, by
$ ||g||_S=\inf\{k\geq 1: g= s_k s_{k-1}\ldots s_1,   s_i\in S, 
1\leq i\leq k\} $.

For $g, h\in G$,   $h\leq g$ if and only if $||h||_S\leq ||g||_S$.

It is clear that relation $\leq$ is reflexsive and transitive,

Question. For $g, h\in G$, Is there a $k\in G$ such that $g\leq k$ and $h\leq k$?

Comment: It appears to me that we should define the empty word to be the identity element, so that the identity has word length zero. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

$\leq$ is a total relation, meaning that for any $g, h\in G-\{e\}$, we have $g\leq h$ or $h\leq g$ (because $\leq$ assigns a natural number to each element and then compares those natural numbers using the standard total order on $\Bbb N$). Thus letting $k$ be whichever of them is largest will work.

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur points out, this is a total ordering. However, it has the unpleasant property of making distinct elements equal (e.g. $(123)=(321)$ in $S_3$, where the generators of $S_3$ are the simple transpositions $(12)$ and $(23)$).

Instead, you could be a bit more careful: define $g<h$ if $||g||_S<||h||_S$ and $g=h$ if, well, $g=h$. Otherwise, the elements are not comparable. In this case, you get a partially ordered set.

In the case of symmetric groups generated by simple transpositions, there is a unique longest element. It is unclear to me whether there is a unique top element in general (for finite groups). For finitely generated groups, there is no reason to have a top element at all (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $S=\{1,-1\}$ and $||n||_S=n$).